# Yii: any way to save the images in compressed form?

Tags: php, image, yii, resize, php-ini

I have images having huge size, I want to compress them before they save in database. Here is my controller, is there any way to do this without any extension?

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Business;
    if (isset($_POST['Business'])) {
        $rnd = rand(0, 9999);

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Business'];

        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
        $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";

        $model->image = $fileName;
        if ($model->save()) {
            $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Are you tried something? [ONE](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/419/image-resize-on-the-fly/) link, [TWO](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/easyimage/) link. [One more](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/) link. [And one more](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=image+resize) links.

Comment: And why without extensions?

Comment: I have visited all of the links before posting my question,and i really wanted to use this extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/ but i donot know where to put this line of code. Yii::import('application.extensions.image.Image');
$image = new Image('images/test.jpg');
$image->resize(400, 100)->rotate(-45)->quality(75)->sharpen(20);
$image->render();

Comment: You can use imagick if it is available in your web server.

Comment: @UsmanIqbal just set [image extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/) to config like this: `'components'=>array(
'image'=>array(
          'class'=>'application.extensions.image.CImageComponent',
            // GD or ImageMagick
            'driver'=>'GD',
            // ImageMagick setup path
            'params'=>array('directory'=>'/opt/local/bin'),
        ),...
)`. After this you can get instance without _import_ like this: `$image = Yii::app()->image->load('images/test.jpg');`

Comment: So where should I write this line in my controller??Before saving image into database or where. Confused totally.

Comment: @UsmanIqbal I did not see your comment... If you want add comment with notification just add `@DanilaHanchar` before your text(it's just advice and tips). So... I think it must will be something like this: `$image = Yii::app()->image->load('path_to_image');
$image->resize(400, 100)->rotate(-45)->quality(75)->sharpen(20);
$image->save(/*null or path_to_small_image*/); $model->image = 'path_to_small_image'`

Comment: @DanilaHanchar in above code of create function, where should I write this code ? $image = Yii::app()->image->load('path_to_image'); $image->resize(400, 100)->rotate(-45)->quality(75)->sharpen(20); $image->save(/*null or path_to_small_image*/); $model->image = 'path_to_small_image'.  This is what i was asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need download [this](https://github.com/zhdanovartur/yii-easyimage) extension and connect it in config like in documentation.
2) After upload original file you need just call method `resize()`. It is works. I checked it. In your case it will be something like this:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Business;
    if (isset($_POST['Business'])) {
        $rnd = rand(0, 9999);

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Business'];

        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
        $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";

        $model->image = $fileName;
        if ($model->validate()) {
           $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName;

           $uploadedFile->saveAs($path);

           $image = new EasyImage($path);
           $thumbPath = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../thumb/' . $fileName;

           $image->resize(100, 100);
           $image->save($thumbPath);

           $model->save();
           $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
       }
   }

   $this->render('create', array(
       'model' => $model,
   ));
}
```

Comment: I did this and it is working my code is  `if ($model->save()) {
                 
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
                $image = Yii::app()->image->load(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
               $image->resize(800, 600);
                $image->save(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
            }` But it is not working for high dimension, Like 7000*4000

Comment: I tried to upload an image having size 7064*4714 and in my models I added this code  `'maxSize'=>5120*3840` in this line, `array('image', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'maxSize'=>5120*3840, 'tooLarge'=>'File has to be smaller than 50MB','safe' => false,'on'=>'insert,update'),`  
` But now instead of giving me the error message it gives me this error. `( ! ) Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 28256 bytes) in G:\www\ba.dev\protected\extensions\image\drivers\Image_GD_Driver.php on line 77`. Why is it so :/

Comment: @UsmanIqbal check your _php.ini_ file. Try to increase next params: 
`upload_max_filesize = 50M; memory_limit = 256M;`

Comment: nothing happened and by the way my php.ini file code is here. `; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize 256M; `

Comment: I accepted your answer, but my problem still persist, but now as my problem was that, a user can upload images, and I wanted to restrict user to upload images having size not larger than 5120*3840, so I changed my mind and restrict my user to upload images only having maxsize equal to 800*600 it is working.

Comment: @UsmanIqbal you can use [THIS](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eimagevalidator/) validator to set range for width and height of image in rules.

Comment: Sir Thanks so much for my help, I dont understand one thing, how can i find that either an image has been uploaded or not, Because when i upload large images, this extension too stays silent, and the page only gets refresh, so what would be the reason???? I think images like 24mb or higher are not uploaded.

Comment: @UsmanIqbal dear friend, I really not understand your question. It may be because today is Saturday. And in my country time around 1AM. But... If you can explain your problem in details I can think about it :)))). So... What  your problem and what you have? My english is not so good... Can you explain more easily youre issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95818/discussion-between-usman-iqbal-and-danila-hanchar).