# how to compress image with fancybox extension on yii 1?

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible? If I want to compress an image while user upload on yii 1? 
**Example:** I have an image with memory 4 MB. when I upload it on yii app, this image will be save on server with 1 MB memory.

What should I do? have other idea? there is any plugin on yii for solve my problems? would do this for save disk memory on my server. thanks for your advice, your comment or your solutions.

here is my fancybox extensions setting :

```
<?php
$this->widget('application.extensions.fancybox.EFancyBox', array(
'target'=>'.various',
'config'=>array(
    'maxWidth'    => 800,
    'maxHeight'   => 600,
    'fitToView'   => false,
    'width'       => 'auto',
    'height'      => 'auto',
    'autoSize'    => false,
    'closeClick'  => false,
    'closeBtn'    =>true,  

   //'title'=>'dfsf',

    'helpers'=>array(
        'title'=>false, // inside or outside
        'overlay'=>array( 'closeClick' => false ), 

    ),
    'openEffect'  => 'elastic',
    'closeEffect' => 'elastic',


),
));
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not at all about the fancybox but about a picture compression just after the upload to the server. How do you upload these pictures? What filetypes are allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii: any way to save the images in compressed form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807051/yii-any-way-to-save-the-images-in-compressed-form)